# ListView Click event

Tags: android, listview

I have a List of Items which I retrieved from my Sqlite DB...
I want to set a Click event for each item. How I can customize this event based on the Item clicked????
Be descriptive... I am a beginner.

This is the method that I used to fill data in my List:

```
private void fillData() {
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    ArrayList db_results = new ArrayList();
    //All Category
    //Cursor cursor = db.getAllTitles();

    //Single Category
    Cursor cursor = db.getTitle(1);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {          
            db_results.add(cursor.getString(4));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    this.list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db_results));
}
```

Comment: What is the different behavior you want when you click on the different list items?  This question is confusing to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `setOnItemClickListener()` on the `ListView`. The `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` listener you provide will be given the position (`0`-based index) and ID (if you were using a `CursorAdapter`, as you should be, rather than converting the `Cursor` into an `ArrayList`), so you will know which item was clicked upon.

Comment: Hi mark, I am looking to do exactly the same thing. Looking on the web ive seen that what you have suggested is the way to do it but I cant find a decent code sample anywhere.

Is there one in your books? If so, page number please :)

Comment: Many of the ListView examples in the books use ListActivity and override onListItemClick(), which (IIRC) gives the same parameters. http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/ for example.

Comment: Thanks once again Mark, looks like exactly what we need :)